# GA4 (not set) in custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I created a custom event that collects banner clicks fro both app and web. I have parameters in the event that collects the banner list name and banner position.

I have created the custom dimension to show this data. It has been a month and when I pull data in explore most of my data goes to not set or blanks.
When I use debugger to test or replicate these instances it is almost impossible because my parameters are always populated.

Is this GA's fault or do I need to improve how we are collecting data? how can I reduce the number of not set and blanks for custom paremeters?

This is the data from GA4 360:

[image]